# Сервисы для публикации мобильных приложений в маркетах - существуют ли?

Tags: google-play, appstore

Не гуглится что-то совсем никак...
Ищу мало-мальски имеющий репутацию сервис, который за умеренную разовую плату размещает под своим аккаунтом разработчика приложения в Гугл/Аппле-маркетах.
Поделитесь, в какую сторону копать, пожалуйста.

P.S. Имеется простенькое разовое приложение для ограниченной аудитории, которое заливать в маркеты, заплатив 100+ баксов, совсем не желается, да и финансы поют романсы.

Comment: Не вижу смысла заливать разовое приложение для ограниченной аудитории. Зачем плодить мусор. 

И стоит оно 25 долл., а не 100+.

И на самый конец, раз так тяжело с финансами, может, зальете в яндексовый магазин. Там, вроде, все как бесплатно.

Comment: @KoVadim, 25 это google play, у яблочников это стоит 100.

Comment: Дело такого рода, что я не программист совсем, состряпал себе простенькое приложение, для расширения аудитории в совем "бизнесовом" начинании. Аппсторе - 99 баксов + Гуглоплей - 25 баксов = 100+ 
Андроид приложение можно установить и в обход плэймаркета, а вот с иос версией - беда.

Comment: @dimiork, желаете связаться с яблоками - платите. Что уж тут говорить, если у них даже адекватный текстовый редактор стоит 70$.

Comment: Вот по сути вопроса услышать бы комментарии...

Comment: Amazon app store, не пробывал, но нигде про цену не нашёл